# How to set synchronized for a network call?

Tags: java, android, database, synchronized

My application submits duplicated data by somehow, I want to prevent that by set the submit method synchronized to make the second call has to wait for the first finish, so the submitted data are deleted locally.

```
static synchronized public void submitStatistics(final User user,
                                    final Consumer<String> onSuccess, final Consumer<Enum.ErrorCode> onError) {
    JSONArray statistics = Statistic.getAllItemsAndConvertToJSONString();
    Rx2AndroidNetworking.post(urlBuilder(SUBMIT_STATISTICS))
            .addQueryParameter(getDefaultParams())
            .addJSONArrayBody(statistics)
            .build()
            .getStringObservable()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new ObserverWrapper<String>(errorCode -> {
                onError.accept(errorCode);
            }) {
                @Override
                protected void onSuccess(String s) {
                    Statistic.deleteSubmittedItems();
                    onSuccess.accept(s);
                }
            });
}
```

Data on server will be duplicated when calling

```
submitStatistics();
submitStatistics();
```

I am finding the reason why it is calling twice at the same time in my app, but I wonder how to apply synchronized for this case. Currently two posts are sent at the same time.

Comment: assume that you class name is `NetworkHelper`, maybe it helps that synchronized on this `NetworkHelper.class`, since every class only loades once.

Comment: But I want other GET methods asynchronized, only POST needs to be synchronized

Comment: `synchronized` is the wrong way to go here. 1.) Your calls to `submitStatistics()` are apparently all being made on the same thread. 2.) `submitStatistics()` returns immediately, anyway, leaving `Rx2AndroidNetworking` background threads to do the heavy lifting. (`submitStatistics()` basically just schedules a "job" which is then executed asynchronously. The POST certainly does not finish before the function returns.) You need to find some way to inhibit calls to `submitStatistics()` until your `onSuccess()` handler runs.